# Service Hook for MS Team in Azure Devops

Tags: azure-devops, microsoft-teams

Hello All i have configured a Service Hook for MS Teams in Azure Devops Server which is  generating Internal Server Error (500),

I was working to bring Pull request approval, deployment approval to MS team which is documented here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops#approve-deployments-from-your-channel

[image]

Response of my service hook
[image]

History
[image]

Comment: Service hook? Did you create web hook? If you want to send messages to channel you can user web-hooks. Could you please check this [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/webhooks-and-connectors/how-to/add-incoming-webhook) for more info.

Comment: @Nikitha-MSFT sorry server hook in my azure devops server

Comment: please reach out to the [product support channels](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/feedback#product-support-channels) for Microsoft Teams.

Answer (score 0):

Which version of Azure Devops Server do you use? How did you configure the Service Hook for MS Teams? For Azure DevOps Services and Azure DevOps 2020 and later versions, we recommend you use the following suite of apps which offer rich features, to integrate with Microsoft Teams.

- [Azure Boards app for Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/boards/integrations/boards-teams?view=azure-devops)
- [Azure Pipelines app for Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/integrations/microsoft-teams?view=azure-devops)
- [Azure Repos app for Teams](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/repos/integrations/repos-teams?view=azure-devops)

Comment: Dong Azure Devops Server 2019 - 17.143.28621.4

Comment: Did you follow the documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/service-hooks/services/teams?view=azure-devops-2019#from-azure-devops-server) to configure Service Hook? How about other team members, did they have this issue?

Comment: Yes images are attached in question

Comment: Did this work ever? Could you login Teams successfully? How about other team members, did they have this issue?